# Wordpress posts with /subdirectory/ in their url, good idea?

Tags: wordpress, url, blog, permalinks

so from what I have seen there there are two ways to do this?!

Install wordpress in a separate subdirectory

Or

Create permalinks.

Why are permalinks a bad idea? A lot of people say that....

Comment: Are you referring to something like `example.com/subdirectory/page`
vs. `example.com/page` ?

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this?

Comment: to make the separation later easier and keep the main site more easily separated from the blog website. If a site is supposed to be bigger and larger, it is silly to have the blog posts and blog look to it... at least I read so online

Answer (score 1):

So... you want to have an arbitrary URL *path segment* that prefixes all your URLs? For example: `example.com/path-segment/slug-of-my-wordpress-post`.

Yes, you can achieve this by either:

- Physically installing WordPress into a subdirectory called `/path-segment`
- Use custom permalinks to create a *virtual* prefix to all your URLs.

But installing in a subdirectory and using "permalinks" is not an either/or decision; you can (and often do) have both.

> Why are permalinks a bad idea? A lot of people say that....

I think there is something missing here? WHo says "permalinks are bad"?

Permalinks are not "bad". They are a fundamental part of WordPress.

> Wordpress posts with /subdirectory/ in their url, good idea?

However, presumably you are asking this from an SEO or usability point of view? In which case it's probably not a good idea, or rather carries no benefit at best.

- Keywords in a URL don't count for much SEO-wise
- Prefixing the same keyword to all URLs is spammy / unnecessary.
- It makes the URL longer for users.

Comment: Separating websites.. So for example a huge website grows. Is it not smart to have multisite installation in the root directory then and simply create 1 more site specially for blog. Then sure, they use the same database but once one wants to move them and separate them if they grow, then in a multisite separation is easier because of tables and the way database is organized. If you install simple wordpress and do not separate them right away, or if you do not do it through multisite installation to make it easy to separate later, you might create trouble later down the road. Right?

Comment: So just creating premalinks will be kind of okay later if you do wish to have a subdirectory with just blog and if you wish to later have such links which clarify that that is the blog, not the main site. However that is a cosmetic solution in right!? It only preserves urls and no need for redirection later, right? So I am thinking about going multisite installation and creating a separate site just for blogging. Later separation will be easier. right? Or am I getting something wrong here.. I really do not want to mess up. I would install wordpress separately in a subdirectory if needed

Comment: @NoobForJS If you have two separate websites then you really need to put one in a physical subdirectory to avoid conflicts of URL. But why do you need two separate website-engines (ie. WordPress installs) when you appear to have a "single" website?

Comment: "If you have two separate websites then you really need to put one in a physical subdirectory to avoid conflicts of URL"" >>> so what is the purpose of wordpress multisite version? I thought it was made for such reasons... So you can have a main site and sites such as members area, blog, special departments websites, etc...

Comment: "But why do you need two separate website-engines (ie. WordPress installs) when you appear to have a "single" website?"">> They should be separate, blog should be a separate website. I do not want to have one single website because if website grows there are other things than blogging that will be done on the website. A blog in my opinion should be a subdomain or subdirectory separate website. And I thought an easy temoporary solution is the wordpress multisite installation, because it is later easier to separate than a regular wordpress installation. Right or wrong?

Comment: @NoobForJS "so what is the purpose of wordpress multisite version?" - You made no mention of "WP multisite" in your question? But, yes, you could use "multisite", but it still sounds like one website to me? In your first comment you state "it not smart to have multisite installation" but later state that "it is later easier to separate than a regular wordpress installation" - so why is it not smart if it is "easier"? (But why would it be "easier"?) However, none of this is actually mentioned in your question - so, what is your question exactly?